# Postgresql query to have atleast two different results for same refrence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following ER Model

[image]

I need to write a postgresql query that does this.

Select all donors where:

```
1)Diagnosis.name starts with "abc".

2)There should be a second Diagnosis.name for the same donor, and it should be "xyz"
```

Consider this as sample data:

Donor table has:

```
id|    name            

1 |John 
2 |Sam
```

Event table has:

```
id | event_type  | donor_fk

1  | diagnosis   | 1 
2  | diagnosis   | 2
3  | diagnosis   | 2
4  | observation | 3
5  | intervention| 3
```

Diagnosis table has:

```
id | name | event_FK

1  |abc   | 2
2  |xyz   | 3
```

I am wondering how can i check if the two instances of diagnosis.name are for the same donor?

The result of the query should return all the data for donor named "Sam".

I am no where close to a solution since i posted this question. I was thinking in the direction of self join of diagnosis table but there is no reference to itself in this table so self join does not make sense.

Comment: You should really attempt the query yourself, and include that query in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the question to suggest which direction i was thinking on..May be you can provide a hint on which way to go from here??

Comment: p.s. RDBM is 'Relational database management system'. I think you wanted to say: 'I have the following schema or Entity Relationship Diagram' Read  lot and have fun, answer is below ;) cheers

Comment: @PawelSz Corrected that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* Not very efficient but a bit readable solution would be: */

---

```
select distinct a.*
from (
    select do.id, do.name
    from diagnosis diag
    join event e on diag.event_fk = e.id 
        and upper(diag.name) like 'ABC%' /* here ya filter 1 */
    join donor do on d.id = e.donor_fk
) a
join (
    select do.id, do.name
    from diagnosis diag
    join event e on diag.event_fk = e.id 
        and upper(diag.name) like 'XYZ'  /* here ya filter 2 */
    join donor do on d.id = e.donor_fk
) b on a.id = b.id
  ;
```